# I want to access local file through xmlHttpRequest on azure in angular 5

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

access local json file on azure unable to fetch json data through xmlhttprequest but work fine in local server.

```
filepath = "/src/assets/config.json";
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (mimeType != null) {
            if (xmlhttp.overrideMimeType) {
                xmlhttp.overrideMimeType(mimeType);
            }
        }
xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else {
              return null;
        }
```

Comment: the path should be relative to your webapp path, so maybe it should be 'assets/config.json'. `src` is a local path and cannot be accessed hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your json file on your Azure webapp , there will be two steps should be done :

1. Create a virtual directory for the physical path that your json file located:
   [image]
2. Due to json file MIME Type is not set by default, upload file named "web.config" with content below to the folder where your json file located :

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Just as below : 
[image]

With this two steps done , you can access json files, pls try it here : https://ukwebapp716.azurewebsites.net/files/aaa.json

Comment: Thanks the issue was mime type on iis server